# Pandas: extract first 4 digits from column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with +1000 columns. I would like to extract only the first 4 digits from all the headers.

Example of the original datafr:

| Q001-XYZ | Q002-XYZ |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

I would like to get:

| Q001 | Q002 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

I tried df.head() = df.head().str[:4] but I get the error SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension is the fastest option:

```py
df.columns = [col[:4] for col in df.columns]
```

[image: timings]

Answer (score 2):

Try via `columns` attribute or via `rename()` method:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('-').str[0]
#OR
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x:x.split('-')[0])
```

OR

```
df.columns=df.columns.str[:4]
#OR
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x:x[:4])
```

Comment: list comprehension is actually fastest: `df.columns = [col[:4] for col in df.columns]`

Comment: @tdy yes sir you are right due to spliting it takes time list comprehension is also a way but `df.columns.str[:4]` is doing the same thing as `[col[:4] for col in df.columns]`

Comment: i agree they follow the same concept, but the comprehension is faster in practice. i went ahead and [posted it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507963/13138364) with a timing plot.

Comment: @tdy That's nice..you answer got selected ***;)*** If you have time can you pls check performace for this as well `list(map(lambda x:x[:4],df.columns))`

Comment: it's very fast but slightly slower than comprehension @AnuragDabas. just updated the plot with this `map` and Pygirl's `.str.extract`

Answer (score 1):

try using `regex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('([\w]+)-', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.columns.str[:4].to_list()
```